# Solr 6 - SUM values of a field along with GROUP BY

Tags: solr, facet, solr6

I have a Solr core having documents with 6 fields as below -

```
FIELDNAME   TYPE    INDEXED   STORED
department  STRING  TRUE      TRUE
group       STRING  TRUE      TRUE
age         INT     TRUE      TRUE
salary      INT     TRUE      TRUE
bonus       INT     TRUE      TRUE
```

What I want is the following -

1. `SUM` the `salary` of all employees from different `department`.
2. `SUM` the `salary` and `bonus` of all employees from different `department`.
3. `SUM` the `salary` of all employees from different `department` and `group`.
4. `SUM` the `salary` and `bonus` of all employees from different `department` and `group`.

Example data -

```
<doc>
  <str name="department">IT</str>
  <str name="group">INFRASTRUCTURE</str>
  <int name="age">27</int>
  <int name="salary">1000</int>
  <int name="bonus">10</int>
</doc>
<doc>
  <str name="department">IT</str>
  <str name="group">DEVELOPMENT</str>
  <int name="age">30</int>
  <int name="salary">10000</int>
  <int name="bonus">100</int>
</doc>
<doc>
  <str name="department">IT</str>
  <str name="group">DEVOPS</str>
  <int name="age">32</int>
  <int name="salary">2000</int>
  <int name="bonus">150</int>
</doc>
<doc>
  <str name="department">IT</str>
  <str name="group">INFRASTRUCTURE</str>
  <int name="age">35</int>
  <int name="salary">20000</int>
  <int name="bonus">200</int>
</doc>
<doc>
  <str name="department">HR</str>
  <str name="group">PEOPLE</str>
  <int name="age">27</int>
  <int name="salary">900</int>
  <int name="bonus">5</int>
</doc>
```

Excepted Output -

```
1. For the 1st requirement -
   IT - 33000
   HR - 900
2. For the 2nd requirement -
   IT - 33460
   HR - 905
3. For the 3rd requirement -
   IT -
      INFRASTRUCTURE - 21000
      DEVELOPMENT - 10000
      DEVOPS - 2000
   HR -
      PEOPLE - 900
4. For the 4th requirement -
   IT -
      INFRASTRUCTURE - 21210
      DEVELOPMENT - 10100
      DEVOPS - 2150
   HR -
      PEOPLE - 905
```

I tried to achieve it by following the directions [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceted+Search), however, I am unable to merge `PIVOT FACET` with the `SUM` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work, untested, might have some typo etc...

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/col/query -d '
  q=*:*&
  json.facet={
   departments:{
    type : terms,
    field : department,
    facet:{
      sumsalary : "sum(salary)",
      sumbonus : "sum(bonus)",
      groups:{
        type : terms,
        field : group,
        facet:{
           sumsalaryg : "sum(salary)",
           sumbonusg : "sum(bonus)"
       }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am also looking to add the values of  `salary` and `bonus` into one value within the group. Can this be achieved? OR I have to add the 2 separately? The real scenario has many fields and sometimes the total of all the fields is required.

Comment: just try it: sum(salary, bonus) the sum FunctionQuery allows multiple inputs, but not sure this one does.

Comment: Does not work. Get an error `org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Expected ')' at position 17 in 'sum(salary,bonus)'`

Comment: then, yes, you need to add them on the client side. Or, you add a field salaryPlusBonus that you can sum() on